# how to tell the compiler that a loop can be safely parallelized?

Tags: fortran

I'm updating a few elements in a large array.

The updates consists of:

1. multiplying the current value by ten (if it's not zero)
2. clearing the current value
3. moving the updated value to a new position in the array

I know there will be no collision when a move occurs.
How can I tell the compiler that it can safely parallelized the loop?

```
do i = 1, 1e6
    if ( v[i] /= 0 ) then
        temp = v[i] * 10
        v[i] = 0
        ndx = get_move_to_ndx(i)
        v[ndx] = temp
    end if
end do
```

I'm on ifort, but I guess this is compiler independent.

Comment: What a strange mixture of Fortran and C...  Not to mention the use of a real end value for the DO loop, which is a deleted feature (not to mention a bad idea.) If you used DO CONCURRENT that would be a clue to the compiler that the loop is suitable for parallelization, but the call needs to be to a PURE procedure. If you don't mind something ifort-specific, then !DIR$ IVDEP might help.

Comment: The above looks a lot like `python` to me.

Comment: It is not possible for the compiler to automatically guess that there will be no collisions.
If you use OpenMP, for instance, with a shared array it should work fine.

Comment: A loop that size should be done quickly. Do you know how long it takes? It is best to start out with an idea of what good enough is, or how it is performing as an ending point or starting point.

Comment: look up fortran directives for your compiler. Here a link to intels compiler ifort directives: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-with-intel-composer-xe-2013-compiler-pragmas-and-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mongrel approach, so you have some ideas using temporary vectors. The WHERE may not be correct, you would have to try it. The Main advantage of WHERE/ELSEWHERE is readability, as it is usually not as fast as loops... Just easier to read.

```
!DIR$ SIMD
FillTemp: Do I = 1, 1000000
  Temps(I) = v(I)*10
ENDDO FillTemp

!$OMP PARALLEL DO
FindIndex: Do I = 1, 1000000
  ndx_vect(I) = get_move_to_ndx(i)
ENDDO FindIndex

WHERE( Temps /= 0 )
  V = 0
ELSEWHERE
  v(ndx_Vect) = tempz
ENDWHERE
```